# Node.js and Express: function return value inside router

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, express, return

I have this block of code:

```
app.get('/oneroute', function(req, res) {
        //get the list of files in directory /myDir
        fs.readdir(myDir, (err, files) => {
            if (err)
            {
                console.log(err);
                throw err;
            }
            if (files)
            {
                console.log(files); //files is an array with all the files in the directory
            }   
            else
            {
                console.log('no files found')
            }
        });
        // I WANT FILES VISIBLE HERE
        res.render('oneroute.ejs');
    });
```

As you can seek inside the renderer i have a small arrow function that puts all the files of a directory inside an array.

I want that array returned to the part where i have commented `//I WANT FILES VISIBLE HERE`, so that i can pass it with `res.render()` to `myDir.ejs`.

How do i do that?
Do i have to pass it to the req object?
How about if a declare a variable inside `app.get()`, and the `fs.readdir()` returns it? But how does it know where to return it to? Can i pass more parameters to `fs.readdir()`? Won't that mess with the function declaration?

EDIT:
I first added the res.render() inside the portion where no files are found.

else
{
console.log('no files found');
res.render('prerenderer.ejs');
}

However, i don't get a `'no files found'` message in my console.
All i get is an empty array `[]`, and the render never occurs. The page just stays where it is.

Comment: Why do you want the `files` to be visible there? There is no obvious reason for that. You can just call  `res.render('myDir.ejs');` inside the callback. Maybe this helps to understand the overall issue: https://felix-kling.de/blog/2019/javascript-callbacks-misconceptions.html

Comment: I want them visible there, so i can pass them to res.render(). I will read the article right now.

Comment: Why don't you call `res.render(files)` (or whatever it should be in the end) inside the callback you pass to `fs.readdir`? That's one of the reasons you are passed a response object: So that you can use it wherever you need it. It doesn't have to be in the route handler itself.

Comment: Well this make sense, thank you. My mind was stuck, in that res.render() should be in the end of the router function.

Comment: @FelixKling I updated the question will an error i had using this approach.

Comment: An array is always truthy, even if it's empty. You might want to do `if (files && files.length > 0)`.

Comment: The error was caused when no files exist, in the else portion of the code.

Comment: Also tried this: else if (!files && files.length < 0). But i get the same output and no redirection.

Comment: Which error? You said *"However, i don't get a 'no files found' message in my console. All i get is an empty array [], and the render never occurs. The page just stays where it is."* That's because `if(files)` is `true` and your a logging the empty array to the console (`console.log(files)`). That's all you do in that branch. The `else` branch is not entered. If you want to enter the `else` branch if no files where found you have to update your condition to what I showed.

Comment: `else if (!files && files.length < 0)` cannot work. If `files` is not defined you cannot access its `length`, which is what the condition currently does. The fact that you got the same result just affirms that the `if(files)` condition is `true` and the first branch (`console.log(files)`) is taken.

Comment: Thanks! I fixed everything by using if (files.length), instead of using if (files). Since even if there are no files, it returns an empty array.